# I want to load my friend's modded save file

Tags: terraria

I can't get my friend's tModLoader world to load fully after copying it to my computer. I have downloaded all the files and loaded up the world, but all the blocks that are added by mods are missing from our world.

Is there any way I can get it to load fully?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like there are some files missing. It's possible that you only grabbed the vanilla version of the world and still need to copy the modded data.

When copying a modded save over to a new computer you need to grab 4 files. These files will be located at `Documents\My Games\Terraria\ModLoader`.

Under the `Worlds` folder you want to grab the `.wld` and `.twld` file for your world.

Under the `Players` folder grab the `.plr` and `.tplr` files of the same name.

The file extensions starting with 't' contain the modded data, which sounds like it would be missing.

If all 4 files are on your computer and you're still having problems, double check that all of the mods your friend has loaded are also enabled in your tModLoader.